# Can "as are" be ambiguous or is "as are" always unambiguous?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "The numbers represented in floating-point notation are not spaced
> evenly along the number line, as are fixed-point numbers."

The statement above uses "as are". Which of these following sentences is the correct interpretation of the statement? is it A or B?

> A. The numbers represented in floating-point notation are not spaced evenly along the number line and "the fixed-point numbers **are not** spaced evenly along the number line."
>
> B. The numbers represented in floating-point notation are not spaced evenly along the number line and "the fixed-point numbers **are** spaced evenly along the number line."

Please provide explanation.

Answer (score 2):

We have the advantage here of knowing that interpretation B is correct and thus what was presumably intended.

I have to agree that the sentence quoted is ambiguous. The “as is(are)” creates no ambiguity when the main clause is stated positively. When, however, the main clause is stated negatively, there is no rule of grammar that specifies whether the negative indicator is carried over by “as.”

My feeling as a native speaker is that the negation is not (as a matter of usage) typically carried over. Instead, when preceded by a clause in the negative, “as is(are)” represents a contrast. That is my feeling and is exemplified by your quotation. I have not, however, found an authority to support that feeling.

Thus, my recommendation is to avoid the “as is(are)” construction unless the main clause is positive.

Comment: Yup. Kittens are not dangerous, as lions are.

Comment: It is a known quality in known animals. If someone is to say, "Sands from beach A are not round but smooth as sands from beach D are."